# NestJS How to configure middleware with async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I'm trying to use bull-arena in a NestJS app.

```
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    const queues = this.createArenaQueues();
    const arena = Arena({ queues }, { disableListen: true });
    consumer.apply(arena).forRoutes('/system/queues');
  }

  createArenaQueues() {
    return [
      {
        name: 'Notification_Emailer',
        hostId: 'MyAwesomeQueues',
        url: 'redis://localhost',
      },
    ];
}
}
```

This works!

But I need to use async/await for `createArenaQueues()`, due to loading queues from db.

```
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    const queues = await this.createArenaQueues();   //await here
    const arena = Arena({ queues }, { disableListen: true });
    consumer.apply(arena).forRoutes('/system/queues');
  }

  async createArenaQueues() {                       // async here
    return [
      {
        name: 'Notification_Emailer',
        hostId: 'MyAwesomeQueues',
        url: 'redis://localhost',
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

Doesn't work!

So, the question, how to handle this?

It wold be cool to run arena from "System" controller, but I couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Also, I tried to move arena to standalone middleware, but dont know, what I should to do in the end: return something like `res.send(arena)` or what?

Easiest way to handle this, is `async` configure support, but it not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#use-factory) for your `arenaQueues` that is created asynchronously:

Add the custom provider to your `AppModule`'s providers:

```
providers: [
  ArenaService,
  {
    provide: 'arenaQueues',
    useFactory: async (arenaService: ArenaService) => arenaService.createArenaQueues(),
    inject: [ArenaService],
  },
],
```

and then inject the `arenaQueues` in your `AppModule`:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(@Inject('arenaQueues') private queues) {}

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    // Now, you can use the asynchronously created this.queues here
    const arena = Arena({ queues: this.queues }, { disableListen: true });
    consumer.apply(arena).forRoutes('/system/queues');
  }
```